# How to use JSONObject.computeIfAbsent without lambda expression

Tags: java, json, lambda

Hello guys I want to know how can I use JSONObject.computeIfAbsent without the use of lambda expression. 
Actually, this is my code

```
list.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> {
            try {
                throw new UnknowClientException("Unkown client : Unable to find client with id" + id);
            } catch (UnknowClientException e) {

            }
        });
```

I want the function to throw my custom exception. I assume that i need to add thows to the signature of the function and I don't know of to do that with lambda expression that's is why I wan to use a "function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in converting the lambda expression into an ordinary class as that doesn’t change the set of permitted exceptions. It’s the implemented `interface` whose declaration determines the allowed exceptions. Implementors of the interface can’t add checked exception to the `throws` clause which weren’t covered by already declared ones of the interface.

If you’re talking about the [`computeIfAbsent` method inherited from the `Map` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), the method to implement is [`Function.apply`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-), which doesn’t allow any checked exception.

As an alternative, you can use

```
result = Optional.ofNullable(list.get(id)).orElseThrow(() -> 
    new UnknowClientException("Unkown client : Unable to find client with id" + id));
```

The generic method [`Optional.orElseThrow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) declares to throw what the provided `Supplier` declares to create, so if `UnknowClientException` is a checked exception, the caller will have to catch or declare it, which seems to be your original intention.

Comment: This is indeed one of the unfortunate consequences of Java's checked exceptions. It is for such reasons that I always inherit my exceptions from `RuntimeException`. :-P

Comment: Hi holgerer thank for your alternative solution it's helps me ! but could you give me à link where i ca learn more about lambda and exception ???