# Java Matcher class to implement toFindResult()

Tags: java, regex, java-8, one-liner

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex), there is a big difference between `find` and `matches()`, still both provide results in some form.

As a kind of Utility the `toMatchResult` function returns with the current results of the `matches()` operation. I hope my assumption under `(1)` is valid. (regex is [here](https://regex101.com/r/6SGAAY/1))

```java
        String line = "aabaaabaaabaaaaaab";
        String regex = "(a*b)a{3}";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line);
        matcher.find();
//        matcher.matches();(1) --> returns false because the regex doesn't match the whole string
        String expectingAab = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println("actually: " + expectingAab);
```

Unfortunately the following in no way works ( Exception: no match found ):

```java
        String line = "aabaaabaaabaaaaaab";
        String regex = "(a*b)a{3}";
        String expectingAab = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line).toMatchResult().group(1);
        System.out.println("actually: " + expectingAab);
```

Why is that? My first assupmtion was that it doesn't work because the regex should match the whole string; but the same exceptio is being thrown with the string value `aabaaa` as well...

Of course the matcher needs to be set to the correct state with `find()`, but what if I'd like to use a oneliner for it? I actually implemented a utility calss for this:

```java
protected static class FindResult{
    private final Matcher innerMatcher;
    public FindResult(Matcher matcher){
        innerMatcher = matcher;
        innerMatcher.find();
    }
    public Matcher toFindResult(){
        return  innerMatcher;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String line = "aabaaabaaabaaaaaab";
    String regex = "(a*b)a{3}";
    String expectingAab = new FindResult(Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line)).toFindResult().group(1);
    System.out.println("actually: " + expectingAab);
}
```

I know full well that this is not an optimal solution to create a oneliner, especially because it puts heavy loads to the garbage collector..

Is there an easier, better solution for this?

It's worth noting, that I'm looking for a solution java8. The matching logic works differently above java 9.

Comment: If you don't want to create new objects, why not just use a static method? You don't need to store any state. Do you just not like the aesthetics of something like `MatcherUtils.findResult(Pattern.compile("...").matcher("..."))`?

Comment: This is actually a valid point! Thanks, this something I'd also accept as an answer, should there be no built-in functionality for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `toMatchResult()` method returns the state of the previous match operation, whether it was `find()`, `lookingAt()`, or `matches()`.

Your line

```java
String expectingAab = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line).toMatchResult().group(1);
```

does not invoke any of those methods, hence, will never have a previous match and always produce a `IllegalStateException: No match found`.

If you want a one-liner to extract the first group of the first match, you could simply use

```java
String expectingAab = line.replaceFirst(".*?(a*b)a{3}.*", "$1");
```

The pattern needs `.*?` before and `.*` after the actual match pattern, to consume the remaining string and only leave the first group as its content. The caveat is that if no match exists, it will evaluate to the original string.

So if you want `matches` rather than `find` semantic, you can use

```java
String expectingNoMatch = line.replaceFirst("^(a*b)a{3}$", "$1");
```

which will evaluate to the original string with the example input, as it doesn’t match.

If you want your utility method not to create a `FindResult` instance, just use a straight-forward `static` method.

However, this is a typical case of premature optimization. The `Pattern.compile` invocation creates a `Pattern` object, plus a bunch of internal node objects representing the pattern elements, the `matcher` invocation creates a `Matcher` instance plus arrays to hold the groups, and the `toMatchResult` invocation creates another object instance, and of course, the `group(1)` invocation unavoidably creates a new string instance representing the result.

The creation of the `FindResult` instance is the cheapest in this row. If you care for performance, you keep the result of `Pattern.compile` if you use the pattern more than once, as that’s the most expensive operation and the `Pattern` instance is immutable and shareable, as explicitly stated in its documentation.

Of course, the string methods `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll` do no magic, but perform the same steps under the hood.

Comment: Premature optimisation is a very good point. [You can't avoid creating objects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149569/189201) :)

Comment: @Sweeper indeed and the actual costs of an object creation depend on its constructor’s work, not the allocation, i.e. a string creation copies the entire character content and `Pattern.compile` does a lot of actual work processing the pattern. Whereas the costs of an ephemeral object with no actual construction work, i.e. impacts on GC, have been analyzed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54619104/2711488) of mine…

Answer (score 3):

The method doesn't need instance fields to work. It can just be a static helper:

```
class MatcherUtils {
  public static MatchResult findResult(Matcher matcher) {
    matcher.find();
    return matcher.toMatchResult();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
MatchResult result = MatcherUtils.findResult(Pattern.compile("...").matcher("..."));
```

Note that you might want to handle the case when `find` can't find anything (Thanks for the one-liner, [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)!):

```
class MatcherUtils {
  public static Optional<MatchResult> findResult(Matcher matcher) {
    return Optional.of(matcher)
             .filter(Matcher::find)
             .map(Matcher::toMatchResult);
    /*
    if (matcher.find()) {
      return Optional.of(matcher.toMatchResult());
    } else {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
    */
  }
}
```